# Open neo4j server from java with existing demo.db folder

Tags: java, neo4j

I want my neo4j server to use my existing `demo.db` folder, when started from java code.

I want it to work just like in windows, where I can select my db folder and then start up my neo4j from neo4j UI.

How can I set the db folder for neo4j, when starting the server from java?

Comment: I updated the question to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to manage neo4j from java code. take a look at [Using Neo4j from Java](https://neo4j.com/developer/java/).
It will help you.

Comment: i already gone through all these documentations but i didn't find any way to perform this task.

Comment: take a look at this page: https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorials-java-embedded. this shows you how simply start neo4j from your java code, run cypher query, ....

Comment: all these documentation methods gives you the data of database any query u can perform and read update and delete. But after the completion to code the database is again closed .i want to up the database so that i can use it in some other program to visualize it. Is this possible.

Comment: yes. it is.  this project is sample of using embedded Neo4j and spring-boot. https://github.com/mantisMolloy/Spring-Boot-Neo4j-Basic/tree/master/src/main/java/SpringBootNeo4j